# ack: Escape single quotes while providing regex

Tags: regex, unix, pcre, ack

I am using ack to search for all values of width enclosed within single or double quotes.

Ex: `width="23"` , `width='420'`

RegEx Pal confirms `/width=("|')\d+\1/g` is the right regex for the job. I am however finding it difficult to supply this regex to ack.

`<prompt>$ ack 'width=("|\')\d+\1'`     <--- Escaping the `'` in the regex like`\'` did not help

`<prompt>$ ack 'width=("|\\\')\d+\1'`     <--- Neither did this.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `"width=(\"|')\d+\1"` . Good luck.

Comment: Or `'width=("|'"'"')\d+\1'`

Comment: @Shawn.. Would you like to provide that as the answer? That worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"width=['\"]\d+['\"]"
```

works for me.  The square brackets define a set of characters containing `'` (by itself) and `\"` (escaped because of the surrounding double-quotes).

It also works with grep, but you need the `-P` option because `\d+` is not part of standard grep regex.